# Plotting geom_segment with position_dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-segment

I have a data set with information of where individuals work at over time. More specifically, I have information on the interval at which individuals work in a given workplace.

```
library('tidyverse')
library('lubridate')

# individual A
a_id <- c(rep('A',1))
a_start <- c(201201)
a_end <- c(201212)
a_workplace <-c(1)

# individual B
b_id <- c(rep('B',2))
b_start <- c(201201, 201207)
b_end <- c(201206, 201211)
b_workplace <-c(1, 2)

# individual C
c_id <- c(rep('C',2))
c_start <- c(201201, 201202)
c_end <- c(201204, 201206)
c_workplace <-c(1, 2)
  
# individual D
d_id <- c(rep('D',1))
d_start <- c(201201)
d_end <- c(201201)
d_workplace <-c(1)

# final data frame
id <- c(a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id)
start <- c(a_start, b_start, c_start, d_start)
end <- c(a_end, b_end, c_end, d_end)
workplace <- as.factor(c(a_workplace, b_workplace, c_workplace, d_workplace))
mydata <- data.frame(id, start, end, workplace)

mydata_ym <- mydata %>%
  mutate(ymd_start = as.Date(paste0(start, "01"), format = "%Y%m%d"),
         ymd_end0 = as.Date(paste0(end, "01"), format = "%Y%m%d"),
         day_end = as.numeric(format(ymd_end0 + months(1) - days(1), format = "%d")),
         ymd_end = as.Date(paste0(end, day_end), format = "%Y%m%d")) %>%
  select(-ymd_end0, -day_end)
```

I would like a plot where I can see the patterns of how long each individual works at each workplace as well as how they move around. I tried plotting a `geom_segment` as I have information of start and end date the individual works in each place. Besides, because the same individual may work in more than one place during the same month, I would like to use `position_dodge` to make it visible when there is overlap of different workplaces for the same id-time. This was suggested in this post here: [Ggplot (geom_line) with overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69587921/ggplot-geom-line-with-overlaps/69588081?noredirect=1#comment123011089_69588081)

```
ggplot(mydata_ym) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = id, xend = id, y = ymd_start, yend = ymd_end), 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.1), size = 2) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.background  = element_rect(fill = "grey97")) +
  labs(y = "time", title = "Work affiliation")
```

The problem I am having is that: (i) the `position_dodge` doesn't seem to be working, (ii) I don't know why all the segments are being colored in black. I would expect each workplace to have a different color and a legend to show up.

Comment: ,@PaulaSpinola Good to see that you followed my downvoted and now deleted suggestion here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595322/ggplot-with-yearmonth-in-x-axis> to use `geom_segment`. :-)

Comment: @TarJae sorry I just downvoted it because it was producing the wrong output, just wanted to make it simpler for the next people to search for this topic. The idea to use `geom_segment` was really good, thanks. I adapted it here correcting some of the issues, but should probably have written it there too. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you include `colour = workplace` in the `aes()` mapping for `geom_segment` you get colours and a legend and some dodging, but it doesn't work quite right (it looks like `position_dodge` only applies to `x` and not `xend` ... ? this seems like a bug, or at least an "infelicity", in `position_dodge` ...

However, replacing `geom_segment` with an appropriate use of `geom_linerange` does seem to work:

```r
ggplot(mydata_ym) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = id, ymin = ymd_start, ymax = ymd_end, colour = workplace),
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.1), size = 2) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev) +
  coord_flip()
```

(some tangential components omitted).

A similar approach is previously documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904364/how-to-jitter-dodge-geom-segments-so-they-remain-parallel) — a near-duplicate of your question once the `colour=` mapping is taken care of ...

Comment: Yes, this works, but only `geom_segment()` allows to set `arrow`, you cannot set that in `geom_linerange()`, so I'm stuck there.